# How, in Rails, do I count the number of times an item has been used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Looking to count the number a times a coupon is being **used** in transactions. However whenever I use count I get `undefined method 'count' for 0:Fixnum`

So my table has:

```
def change
  create_table :coupons do |t|
    t.string :code
    t.string :applies_to
    t.decimal :amount_off, precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.integer :percent_off
    t.integer :max_redemptions
    t.integer :used, :default => 0
    t.datetime :redeem_by
    t.boolean :active, default: true
    t.timestamps null: false
  end
end
```

Then in my view:

```
<% @coupons.each do |coupon| %>
  <%= coupon.code %>
  <%= coupon.used %>
<% end %>
```

When I use `<%= coupon.used.count %>` I get the above error.

I've tried several variations of this including:

- `<%= coupon.count(:used) %>` which results in: undefined method
  `count';
- `<%= coupon.group(:used).count %>` which results in: `undefined method
  'group'`.
- I've also tried: `<%= coupon.includes(:used).inject(0) {|sum, c| sum +
  c.used.count}%>`. End up with `undefined method 'includes'`.
- `<%= coupon.used.inject(0) {|sum, c| sum + c.used}%>` results in `undefined method`inject' for 0:Fixnum`

So...how do I get the total number of times the coupon has been used?

Edit: So apparently it's not incrementing. I updated my controller to be:

```
def index
 @coupons = TbCommerce::Coupon.ordered.paginate(:page => params[:page])
 if params[:search]
  @coupons = @coupons.search(params[:search])
 end
 @coupons.increment!(:used)
 respond_with @coupons
end
```

This works...kind of. It looks like it's just applying to the number of times the page is being loaded not the number of times it's been used.

Further review:
So it looks like the previous developer did apply incrementation it's just not applying. There's a validation that has the following:

```
def increment_coupon_used
 coupon.increment_used! if coupon.present?
 return true
end
```

Then the model has:

```
def increment_used!
 update(:used => used + 1)
end
```

I attempted to update the increment_used! to update_attributes(:used => used +1) to no avail.

Comment: "When I use <%= coupon.used.count %>" - what are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: Trying to get a count of the number of times the coupon has been used

Comment: that's simply `coupon.used`

Comment: Right but it's not incrementing. It's staying at 0

Comment: Of course. Because you're not incrementing it. Reading is reading. Separate from incrementing/updating.

Comment: *It looks like it's just applying to the number of times the page is being loaded not the number of times it's been used* It's because your `@coupons.increment!(:used)` is not in the good workflow, it should be in an update method i'm guessing, not index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `used` is an integer column on `Coupon`, you would simply call:

```
<%= coupon.used %>
```

Comment: However it's not actually updating. It's staying at 0

Comment: That's a different problem. In your code where you are recording the use of a `Coupon`, you need to `increment` the `used` column on `Coupon`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your request, you're trying to get number of times a `coupon` is being used. So, my answer will be;

```
Coupon.group(:code).sum(:used)
```

Since you're trying to know the number of times one `coupon` is used by code and guessing the `used` column stores how many times you used it, you should have a `sum` instead of a `count`.

Comment: You think there are multiple coupons with the same code, each with its own value of `used`?

Comment: `Looking to count the number a times a coupon is being used in transactions`, I'm pretty sure that's what he need by the comment he made.

Comment: Indeed, his DB schema looks weird. I can see how one can infer your version of interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like you are trying to inject over an integer value, which is not correct. Why don't you simply print **coupon.used**

This is what you want. Don't try Kernel class **inject** method over integer, it is basically for sort of collection of integers like **array**.